# Microsoft Access 2000 Database tables not displaying after removing security

Tags: database, visual-studio, ms-access

I have a database that has essentially been unlocked: I've removed the database password and VBA query password, but for some reason there is no content in the database... but the structure and fields are still in place.

I've discovered that the application its working with has been placing all of the actual data in windows virtual store in the app data folder. Based on testing, I'm 100% confident that the data is in this database.

Is there something that I'm missing - maybe another password lock I've forgotten - that would cause this strange behavior?

Comment: "*there is no content in the database... but the structure and fields are still in place*" Does that mean the db contains tables but they are empty?  If so, check for hidden and system tables which may contain the data you believe to be stored in the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the tables were hidden.

To fix it in microsoft access 2007:

I clicked the microsoft button while the db was open, and then went to Access Options -> Current Database -> and checked "Display Navigation Pane". After that, i went to Navigation options under the current database menu and checked "show hidden objects" and "show system objects".

Fixed the problem!